# Call an API using superagent?

Tags: api, reactjs, superagent

I have an API that consists this branch of data

```js
{
  "data": {
    "id": ,
    "title": ,
    "description": ,
    "old_price": "100",
    "new_price": "50",
    "size": "50",
    "quantity": 20,
  },
  "errors": null,
  "code": 1
}
```

I am using superagent in order to call the API and render this information, but I am doing it in wrong way.

Here my code

```js
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import superagent from 'superagent';
import Layout from './components/Layout';

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state={
      name:''
    }
  }
    componentDidMount(){
        console.log('componentDidMount');

        const url='http://...';
        superagent
        .get(url)
        .query(null)
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .end ((error, response)=>{
            const title=response.body.response
            console.log(JSON.stringify(title));
            
            this.setState({
              name:title
            })
        })
        
    }
  render(){
    return(
      <Layout data={this.state}/>
    )
  }
}


render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Here I render it

```js
import React from 'react';

export default class Layout extends React.Component{
    render(){
        let data = this.props.data;
        return (
            <div> 
                 {data.name}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

But is not rendering, I think I am doing in wrong way. Please could you help me with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const title=response.body.response
```

Should be

```
const title=response.body
```

most likely

Comment: Hey, thank u it worked! of course, I did some couple of adjustments, but this was a starting point)

Answer (score 1):

For me something like this is working:

```
import request from 'superagent';

getFooFromServer() {
  const url='http://...';
  request.get(`${url}/foo`)
    .accept('json')
    .then(res => {
      //Do something with your data
    }
    catch(error => {
      //Do something with the error
    };
}
```